# Xbee XB24-ACI range without antenna

Tags: radio, xbee

Anybody have experience with the range of these xbee modules? I reading about 10 kilometers:

http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/what-is-the-maximum-range-of-an-xbee-lets-find-out

But according to my previous research with 433mhz radio modules like these:

http://www.instructables.com/id/RF-315433-MHz-Transmitter-receiver-Module-and-Ardu/

cant even do 15 meters indoors with antenna. I want to make sure this xbee XB-24 will be able to do 10 meters indoors without an antenna. The 2 units separated only by a wood ceiling.

Thanks.

Comment: And your actual question is?

Comment: what is the range of the xbee modules in meters without antenna?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out from this article.

http://diychristmas.org/vb1/showthread.php?3086-XBee-Antenna-Types

That blue square I have on the xbees are actually antennas. It claims that it is good for 24 meters which is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without eyes I cannot see. Without ears I cannot hear. Without a mouth I cannot speak.

Without an antenna there is no range.

However, imperfections in components and PCB tracking will allow small electric or magnetic fields to emanate from devices but there is no information that can allow you to estimate range. Try it.